# Мягкие и йотированные гласные

Tags: фонетика

Сколько звуков содержит гласный звук в слове "сядь"?
Ведь Я здесь не йотированная, которая состоит из созвучия [йа] и мы не говорим [с"йадь].

Comment: Вопрос не совсем ясен. "Сколько звуков содержит ...звук". Звук он и есть звук, он один и ничего не содержит. Вы хотели спросить, какие гласные и согласные звуки в этом слове?

Comment: Мягкими могут быть только согласные. К гласным это понятие неприменимо.

Comment: М_Г.  Общепринятая мягкая гласная И соответствует звуку [и]  Два звука это уже   не звук а созвучие например Е йотированная [йе] которую признают как [йэ], хотя если выделить два звука [й] и [э] , и объединить их мы не получим желаемой Е, проверено в звукозаписи.

Comment: @М_Г все-таки иногда говорят о мягких гласных

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1):

В этом слове один гласный звук - [а].

Comment: Я могу доказать звуковой фонограммой, что если соединить Мягкий звук [c] с [а] , то вы не получите желаемого СЯ пока не вставите между ними неизвестный вам звук [я], который пока у нас не узаконен.

Comment: @ВикторЛ , Вы хотите сказать новое слово в фонетике?

Answer (score 1):

Буквы е, ё, ю, я называются йотированными (йотованными), потому что а) когда они стоят после согласных звуков, эти согласные — мягкие (заимствования — отдельная история), порой говорят о так называемом «йотовом призвуке» у мягких согласных; тогда эти буквы обозначают звуки ['э], ['о], ['у] и ['а] соотв.; б) в позиции начала слова, а также после гласных они обозначают сочетания звуков [j'э], [j'о],[j'у] и [j'а] соотв., где, очевидно, присутствует тот самый йот.

В слове *сядь* три звука: [с' а т']. *Я* обозначает один звук потому, что стоит после согласного, звук [j'] просто не произносится.